# Get specific file for every week using ls command

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, ls

Could someone help me to get the file for every week using `ls` command?

```
ls -t {path} | grep -e "-1700" | head -30 | sort -r
```

With this `ls` command, I got below mentioned output

```
2022.05.30-1700
2022.05.28-1700
2022.05.26-1700
2022.05.25-1700
2022.05.22-1700
2022.05.21-1700
2022.05.18-1700
2022.05.17-1700
2022.05.16-1700
2022.05.15-1700
2022.05.14-1700
2022.05.13-1700
2022.05.12-1700
2022.05.09-1700
2022.05.08-1700
2022.05.02-1700
2022.04.26-1700
2022.04.24-1700
2022.04.23-1700
2022.04.21-1700
2022.04.17-1700
2022.04.16-1700
2022.02.25-1700
2022.02.19-1700
2022.02.12-1700
2022.02.11-1700
2022.01.29-1700
2022.01.23-1700
2022.01.22-1700
2022.01.15-1700
```

But we need only one build for every week

example like this:

```
2022.05.21-1700
2022.05.14-1700
2022.05.07-1700
...
...
...
```

Comment: `2022.05.07-1700` is among your expected output, but it's not in your input.

Comment: What about this?: Get the first file, remember the date (maybe via `touch -r`), then find the next file that is at least 7 days newer than the first one. Then repeat until there are no more files left. That procedure is assuming that a file like `2022.01.15-1700` was actually created at 17:00 on January 15th 2022, of course; actually it would work with any name then.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to pick the ones from Saturdays and that you're on a GNU system, you could do:

```
ls {path} |
  tr .- '- ' |
  LC_ALL=C date -uf - '+%A %Y.%m.%d-%H%M' |
  grep -Po '^Saturday \K.*-1700'
```

With `zsh` (and on any system), you could do the same using a glob qualifier function:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
On{Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fru,Sat,Sun} () {
  local t
  TZ=UTC0 strftime -rs t %Y.%m.%d-%H%M $REPLY:t &&
    TZ=UTC0 LC_ALL=C strftime -s t %a $t &&
    [[ $0 = On$t ]]
}
```

and then:

```
print -rC1 -- <1900-2100>.<1-12>.<1-31>-1700(N+OnSat)
```

For the ones on Saturdays.

On your sample, they give:

```
2022.01.15-1700
2022.01.22-1700
2022.01.29-1700
2022.02.12-1700
2022.02.19-1700
2022.04.16-1700
2022.04.23-1700
2022.05.14-1700
2022.05.21-1700
2022.05.28-1700
```

You'll notice that there are some gaps, as there's not one file for every Saturday.

To get one per week (the latest of each week), where weeks run from Sunday to Saturday, you could do:

```
ls -r {path} |
  tr .- '- ' |
  date -uf - '+%Y%U %Y.%m.%d-%H%M' |
  uniq -w6 |
  cut -d' ' -f2
```

Which on your sample gives:

```
2022.05.30-1700
2022.05.28-1700
2022.05.21-1700
2022.05.14-1700
2022.05.02-1700
2022.04.26-1700
2022.04.23-1700
2022.04.16-1700
2022.02.25-1700
2022.02.19-1700
2022.02.12-1700
2022.01.29-1700
2022.01.22-1700
2022.01.15-1700
```

(not all being on Saturdays).

For weeks running from Monday to Sunday, replace `%Y%U` with `%G%V` (the ISO week year and number). That one would also work correctly around changes of years as the `%G` and `%V` only change between the 31<sup>st</sup> of December and the 1<sup>st</sup> of January if the 31<sup>st</sup> is a Sunday while `%Y%U` gives `202152` on Friday 2021-12-31 and `202200` on Saturday 2022-01-01 for instance.

Those are the only two options with `%` formatting sequences supported by `date`. For [weeks starting on different days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_the_days_of_the_week#/media/File:First_Day_of_Week_World_Map.svg) we'd need to be take a different approach.

For example, we could use the epoch time for the corresponding date interpreted as UTC, divided by the number of seconds in a week, properly offset for the required first day of the week which would also avoid problems around the first day of the year.

For instance, for weeks starting on Sunday:

```
ls -r {path} |
  tr .- '- ' |
  date -uf - '+%s %Y.%m.%d-%H%M' |
  awk '{week = int(($1 / 86400 - 3)/ 7)}
       week != last {print $2}
       {last = week}'
```

Replace `- 3` with `- 4` for weeks starting on Monday, or `- 2` for weeks starting on Saturday.

Or with `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
typeset -A latest=()
for f (<1900-2100>.<1-12>.<1-31>-1700(N))
  TZ=UTC0 strftime -rs t %Y.%m.%d-%H%M $f &&
  latest[$(( (t / 86400 - 3) / 7 ))]=$f
print -roC1 -- $latest
```